# обособление "то есть", "такие(,) как" и пунктуация в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Попалось очень сложное предложение, в котором необходимо расставить знаки препинания. Сначала я сделал так:

*Великие мыслители, такие как Лао-цзы, придумали свои теории Дао, зашифровывая их, боясь донести до простого народа, потому что они понимали:  как только все люди поймут основу своего “я” и самоидентифицируются,  управлять, то есть манипулировать ими, будет чрезвычайно тяжело.*

Но мне исправили на вот такой вариант:
*Великие мыслители, такие, как Лао-цзы, придумали свои теории Дао, зашифровывая их, боясь донести до простого народа, потому что они понимали: как только все люди поймут основу своего “я” и самоидентифицируются  - управлять, то есть, манипулировать ими будет чрезвычайно тяжело.*

Как же правильно? Все-таки нужна запятая в обороте "такие, как", и нужно ли выделять "то есть" запятыми. Где можно посмотреть четко сформулированное правило?

Answer (score 8):

Правильного варианта в двух приведённых нет, но тот, кто взялся за исправление первоначального текста, совсем не сечёт в ВМПС им. Тургенева (с).

Оба сложных момента - с *такие как* и *то есть* - хорошо, с примерами, изложены в учебниках. Но Грамота.ру, имхо, компактнее излагает.

Оборот с пояснительными членами предложения обособляется с двух сторон:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Вашем случае пояснением к "управлять ими" будет "то есть манипулировать". Вот после манипуляций и следует закрыть запятую. Хотя она и плохо смотрится...

Подробно об [**обособлении уточняющих и пояснительных оборотов**](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_179).

---

А на постановку запятой в "такие как" влияет наличие прилагательного, предшествующего уточняющему обороту:

> запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой», если
> слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным: Погода
> **дождливая, такая как осенью**. Обстановка в этом доме была **мрачная,
> такая как в старинных замках** (ср.: Погода такая, как осенью.
> Обстановка в этом доме была такая, как в старинных замках).

Правило [полностью](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть в Вашем первом варианте нужно всего лишь перенести одну запятую:

*Великие мыслители, такие как Лао-цзы, придумали свои теории Дао, зашифровывая их, боясь донести до простого народа, потому что они понимали: как только все люди поймут основу своего “я” и самоидентифицируются, управлять, то есть манипулировать, ими будет чрезвычайно тяжело.*

А можно ли поменять порядок слов? Тогда шероховатость снимется:

*...управлять ими, то есть манипулировать, будет чрезвычайно тяжело.*

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь даже спрашивать, кто и где и по какому праву "исправил" ваш вариант. )) Лично я в указанном первоначальном предложении нашел только две ошибки.

Первая: запятая после слова "ими".
Вторая: повтор слова ("понимали" и "поймут").

Я бы написал так:

"Великие мыслители, такие как Лао-цзы, придумали свои теории Дао, зашифровывая их, боясь донести до простого народа, потому что они понимали: как только все люди осознают основу своего "я" и самоидентифицируются, управлять, то есть манипулировать, ими будет чрезвычайно тяжело".

Предложение в целом типичное и характерное для научных источников, так что смысловая и "терминистская" перегруженность не должна вас смущать. А исправлявшему - ба-а-альшой привет! ))

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю, кто вам правил пунктуацию, но но трижды неправ.
И не вижу особой сложности в предложении. Все вполне по стандартным правилам.

Запятая перед "как" нужна.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722

В конструкции "такой, как" запятая ставится всегда, за исключением двух случаев, Ваше предложение не подпадает под эту оговорку.

В отношении "то есть". Здесь это союз, запятая нужна перед ним, но не после.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_733

Теоретически можно представить "то есть" в роли вводного слова, междометия, но это редчайший случай, стилизация и точно не в такой фразе.

Ну а тире я просто не понимаю в данном случае. Ну да, есть такая рекомендация ставить тире, если две части бессоюзного сложного сами по себе достаточно осложнены, но у нас-то и части простые, и предложение сложноподчиненное ("как только" - союз подчинительный).

Ваш исходный вариант выглядит если не стопроцентно правильным, то во всех отношения правильней "правленного".

Вашу фразу можно немного покритиковать с позиций стилистики (например "*понимали*: как только *поймут*" - не самый удачный выбор, но но это я не буду сейчас без вашего на то запроса.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я правильно понял, что лучше всего оставить так: Великие мыслители, такие, как Лао-цзы, придумали свои теории Дао, зашифровывая их, боясь донести до простого народа, потому что они понимали: как только все люди поймут основу своего “я” и самоидентифицируются, управлять, то есть манипулировать ими будет чрезвычайно тяжело.

Comment: Не совсем. Я имел в виду, что после "ими" запятая, она у вас же была. А вот теперь и сам засомневался... В таком варианте запятая точно нужна, но вот после "ими" или перед - уже можно обсуждать. Вы подождите, здесь есть люди куда более опытные, думаю ответят. Остальное - да.

Answer (score -1):

**Предлагаемый вариант:**

Великие мыслители, **такие как Лао-цзы,** придумали свои теории Дао, зашифровывая их, боясь донести до простого народа, потому что они понимали: как только все люди поймут основу своего “я” и самоидентифицируются, **то** управлять, **а точнее манипулировать** ими будет чрезвычайно тяжело.

**Сравним варианты конца предложения**

(1)...управлять, то есть манипулировать ими, будет чрезвычайно тяжело (глагол"управлять" обособлен от дополнения "ими").

(2)...управлять, то есть манипулировать, ими будет чрезвычайно тяжело (такое управление дополнением также нежелательно).

(3) **Предлагается замена союза ТО ЕСТЬ союзом А ТОЧНЕЕ**: управлять, **а точнее** манипулировать ими будет чрезвычайно тяжело.

**Сравнить у Лопатина § 81.:** Отчет о том, каких высот, **а точнее** глубин удалось добиться в познании природы...

Глаголы управлять (нейтр.) и манипулировать (негат.) **нетождественны по значению.** МАНИПУЛИРОВАТЬ 2. кем-чем. Публиц. Пытаться воздействовать на поведение людей в своих целях, представляя кого-, что-л. в искажённом, ложном виде. УПРАВЛЯТЬ 4. Направлять, определять поступки, поведение, взгляды и т.п. кого-л.